# canActivate causing constant refresh - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to use the canActivate feature on my app routing, however whenever I compile the app the log shows constantly refreshing with fail messages that I had console.log()'d out for visibility.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: if you're not using `pathMatch: 'full'` on your empty route you are going to end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting to the wrong route in your **`canActivate`** method. Redirect to **`login`**. Here are the change you need to make:

```
// if not logged in, navigate to login screen
this.router.navigate(['login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
```

When you are redirecting to **`''`**, it goes again to the **`canActivate`** guard, hence the infinite loop.

[image]

Comment: Ah great! I must have missed this when I was switching back and forth between testing the different pages. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`this.router.navigate([''], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});`

will get executed everytime when not logged in, thus causing your infinite redirects as in your router config

`{path: '', component: HomepageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},`

Add an explicitly path for an e.g. LoginComponent.
And `{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}` should also point to some kind of CatchUnmatchedPathComponent where a User gets some kind of 404 page represented.

Answer (score 1):

You are navigating to root by `this.router.navigate([''], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});` which causes the guard to kick in again therefore it gets in the loop.

Try `this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});`

Comment: I honestly believe it can as I am using that all the time when using `navigate`. It cannot start with `/` in route definitions.